# Excel Percentile Array Formula for Values within Date Range

Tags: arrays, excel, date, if-statement, percentile

I'm trying to find the 90th percentile of values within a date range. I'm currently using this array formula:

```
{=PERCENTILE(IF(AND(E2<Combined_clean!F$2:F$220828,C2>=Combined_clean!F$2:F$220828),Combined_clean!J$2:J$220828),0.9)}
```

in which E2 is the lower bound for the date range, C2 is the upper bound, F2:F220828 within the Combined_clean sheet is the date values of the data, and J2:J220828 is the data values. Every time I try to run this I get a "#Value!" error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Array formulas do not like AND  use `*` instead

```
=PERCENTILE(IF((E2<Combined_clean!F$2:F$220828)*(C2>=Combined_clean!F$2:F$220828),Combined_clean!J$2:J$220828),0.9)
```

Comment: Still getting an error message. "Value used in the formula is the wrong data type". The dates are all in the date format, the values in general format. The percentile works fine without an array.

Comment: try: `=AGGREGATE(16,6,(Combined_clean!J$2:J$220828)/((E2<Combined_clean!F$2:F$220828)*(C2>=Combined_clean!F$2:F$220828)),0.9)`

Comment: Have the dates been imported from anywhere? Select column F and click Text to Columns under the data tab and select Date when you get to the page with Data Column Format.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The Aggregate formula worked beautifully